# Question about points of a variety lying in an extension as K-morphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I hope that someone can shed some light on this for me.. or at least point me to some references.

Suppose that $X$ is an algebraic (let's just say affine) variety defined over $k$. 
 Suppose I have a subfield $K$ of $k(X)$. We fix an algebraic closure $\bar{K}$ of $K$, and we can consider $\bar{K}$-points of $X$: which by definition is the collection of $k$-morphisms from $k[X] \rightarrow \bar{K}$. Alternatively, we can think of these as morphisms from a model variety $Z$ defined over $k$ where $k(Z) = L$ is an algebraic extension of $K$ to $X$.

Now I am interested instead in $K$-homomorphisms $K[X] \rightarrow \bar{K}$. 
I believe that I can see this set as $X_{K}(\bar{K})$, that is.. $\bar{K}$-points of the $K$-variety $X_{K} = mSpec( k[X] \otimes_{k} K )$.

If everything I am saying seems OK.. I need to ask, how does $X_{K}(\bar{K})$ relate to $X(\bar{K})$? I know that $X(\bar{K})$ can be identified with $X_{\bar{K}}(\bar{K})$..

The set of $K$-homomorphisms $K[X] \rightarrow \bar{K}$ can be given a variety structure through the identification with $X_{K}(\bar{K})$.. Can I in some sense see $X_{K}(\bar{K})$ as a subvariety of $X(\bar{K})$?
It should be true that $X_{K}(\bar{K}) \subset X(\bar{K})$, correct? A $K$-homomorphism $K[X] \rightarrow \bar{K}$ restricts to a $k$-homomorphism from $k[x] \rightarrow \bar{K}$

Thank you!